# Who blew the shofar during Matan Torah?

Tags: shofar, shemot-exodus, har-sinai

During Matan Torah, the shofar was heard by the entire nation but who blew it? Was it Moshe? Angels? The text does not specify. Is there midrash to address this?

Comment: Or maybe nobody blew it, there was just this noise of a Shofar which everyone heard, and there wasn’t a literal Shofar at all?

Comment: @DonielF, I remember hearing that it was the horn of the ram at akeidas yitzchak, and that the other one will be blown at the time of moshiach

Answer (score 2):

Well, my hunch is correct, at least from one Acharon!!

See [Or Hachayim on Shemot 19:19](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9596&st=&pgnum=294) - "Moshe spoke and God answered him in a voice". According to Or Hachayim, "the voice" refers to the voice of the shofar.

(Keep in mind that this is just **one of many** interpretations of what the term "voice" is.)

Comment: Shemot 19:19 "The blare of the shofar grew louder and louder. As Moses spoke, G-d answered him in THUNDER." The Torah seems to specify G-d answered Moshe with thunder but doesn't specify the use of the shofar.

Comment: Or Hachayim was not a rishon.

Comment: @Ephraim77, obviously Or Hachayim translated that word differently, then.

Comment: @Ephraim77 The word in the passuk is קול, which literally means “voice.”

Comment: @DonielF You've missed something, I'm afraid. קול could also mean "thunder". See a few psukim earlier when the whole event is introduced. *Vayehi kolot ubrakim...* There *kolot* means thunder(s).

Comment: @DanF I didn’t miss anything. I’m aware that the word can refer to thunder, but fundamentally it refers to a voice of any kind, which lends itself to being interpreted differently in different contexts.

Comment: @DonielF My apologies for a wrong, quick assumption. Technically, it **could** mean "thunder", though, probably not, within this context. But again, on initial reading, I wouldn't have thought that it meant "Shofar" until I thought about what the beginning of the verse said, and Or Hachayim confirmed it. Again, this is just one opinion. Many of the other commentaries do confirm that it was G-d's "voice."